# Why do I get garbage values when I input 't' two times?

Tags: c, uart, interrupt-handling, msp430, microprocessors

I am attempting to implement a temperature sensor on the MSP430G2553 that reads and outputs temp readings and also timestamps. The basic requirements are as follows:

• t: Show the current time of the system. Output to the serial terminal the current time of the system using the form hhmmss, where hh is the two digit hour in 24-hour format, mm is the two digit minute in the hour, and ss is the two digit second within the minute.

• s: Set the current time of the system. Set the current time of the system to the provided argument. There will be no space between the command and its argument. The argument will be on the form hhmmss, where hh is the two digit hour in 24-hour format, mm is the two digit minute in the hour, and ss is the two digit second within the minute.

• o: Show the oldest temperature reading and its timestamp. Output to the serial terminal the oldest temperature reading and its timestamp. The output must have the form hhmmss: T, where hh is the two digit hour in 24-hour format, mm is the two digit minute in the hour, ss is the two digit second within the minute, and T is the measured temperature. The displayed entry must be removed from the list. If no readings have been performed, the message “No temperatures recorded.” must be displayed.

• l: Show all the temperature readings and their timestamps. Output to the serial terminal all the temperature readings and their timestamps. The output should be in chronological order, oldest ﬁrst. The output must have the form hhmmss: T, where hh is the two digit hour in 24-hour format, mm is the two digit minute in the hour, ss is the two digit second within the minute, and T is the measured temperature. All entries must be removed from the list. If no readings have been performed, the message “No temperatures recorded.” must be displayed.
Your system must also meet the following requirements:

• You must capture a new temperature reading every ﬁve (5) minutes and store 32 temperature readings at a minimum. If you have reached the maximum amount of temperature readings, discard the oldest one before storing a new one.

An error occurs after inputting 't' 2 times. The next time I input 't', It outputs 3 or 4 garbage values. My 't' case in the switch statement runs perfectly fine when I comment out the 's' case or change 's' to a different variable but that case  for the assignment needs to be in the case 's' is input into the uart. What I've tried so far includes: changing the variable, commenting out the second case, changing the value of the S case to make sure the garbage values were resulting because of that case, playing with bracketing of certain parts of code, revamped the entire first part of the t case to be more efficient and still came out with the same error,etc. Any suggestions would be very helpful. [Picture of Garbage Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYSAC.png)

```
#include "msp430g2553.h"

volatile short unsigned int i=0,j=0,k=0;//This the integer that track the number of cycles
volatile short unsigned int timercount=0;//This the integer that track the number of cycles
volatile unsigned int GT=2600;//variable that sets the global time in seconds of the system
volatile char inputcharacters[16];//Input character storage array
volatile unsigned int tempature[32];//
volatile unsigned int tempaturetime[32];
volatile unsigned int d[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0},test[7];
volatile unsigned int h=0;
volatile unsigned int m=0;
volatile unsigned int ss=0;
int temp=0;

void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;//Disabling watchdogtimer

    P1DIR |= BIT0;//setting p1 bit 1 to outy
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;//Shutting off the LED

    /* UART config for 9600 baud with SMCLK*/
    IE2 = 0x00;//interrupts off on UART
    UCA0CTL1 = 0x81;//using SMCLK(1Mhz) and software reset enable
    UCA0CTL0 = 0x00;//eight data bits, no parity, one stop bit
    UCA0MCTL = 0x02;//Setting UCBRSx to 1 to set clock rate to 9600
    UCA0BR0 = 0x68;//set clock rate to 9600 from 1Mhz
    UCA0BR1 = 0x00;//set clock rate to 9600
    UCA0STAT = 0x00;//error check and parity, and frame error check all off

    TACTL = 0x1D0;// sets timer a to use the 32.768kh clock with 8 divisor and in up mode
    TACCR0 = 0x1001;// setting the timer to count up to 4097 to get a 1hz(1s) oscillation
    TACCTL0 &= 0xFFEF;// disable capture compare interrupts

    P1SEL|=0X06;// According to slas735j both p1.1(0X02) and p1.2(0X04) need to be set on to receive and send on the UART
    P1SEL2|=0X06;

    ADC10CTL0 &= ENC;
    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 | ADC10SHT_3 | REFON | ADC10ON;
    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_10 | ADC10DIV_2 | ADC10SSEL_3;
    //ADC10CTL0 = 0x3030;
    //ADC10CTL1 = 0xA038;
    ADC10CTL0 &= 0xFFFC;

    /* Enable USCI logic and Enable interrupts */
    UCA0CTL1 &= 0xFE;//turning on USCI logic
    IE2 = 0x01;// Sets UART to receive interrupt
    TACCTL0 = CCIE;// set timerA interupts on done last
    __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE);//found on TI wiki
}

#pragma vector=USCIAB0RX_VECTOR// This vector name was pulled from the webcources code
__interrupt void uartinput(void)//this form found on TI's wiki
{
    inputcharacters[i] = UCA0RXBUF;
            UCA0TXBUF = UCA0RXBUF;
            if((i>14)||(inputcharacters[i]=='\r'))
                    {if(inputcharacters[i]=='\r'){inputcharacters[i]=0;}//to reduce i, the number of inputs so that we dont count the \r
                      for(j=0;j<i;j++){switch(inputcharacters[j]) {//switch statement that check the input characters and outputs the correct morse
                      case 't' :

                          h=GT/3600;
                          m=(GT-h*3600)/60;
                          ss=GT-h*3600-m*60;

                          d[0]=(h/10);
                          d[1]=(h-(d[0]*10));
                          d[2]=(m/10);
                          d[3]=(m-(d[2]*10));
                          d[4]=(ss/10);
                          d[5]=(ss-(d[4]*10));
                          for(k=0;k<6;k++)
                          {while((IFG2 & 0x02)==0)
                          {;}
                          UCA0TXBUF=d[k]+48;
                          test[k]=d[k]+48;}
                          while((IFG2 & 0x02)==0)
                                {;}
                          UCA0TXBUF='\r';
                          break;
                      case 'x' ://If this break case is not set to 's' it will not cause the error in the 't' case, no idea why
                          GT=0;
                          temp=(inputcharacters[j+1]-0x30)*10;//
                          temp+=(inputcharacters[j+2]-0x30);
                          GT+=(temp*3600);
                          temp=(inputcharacters[j+3]-0x30)*10;
                          temp+=(inputcharacters[j+4]-0x30);
                          GT+=(temp*60);
                          temp=(inputcharacters[j+5]-0x30)*10;
                          temp+=(inputcharacters[j+6]-0x30);
                          GT+=temp;
                          j+=7;
                         break;
                      case 'o' :
                          {;}
                          break;
                      case 'l' :
                          {;}
                          break;
                      case '\r' :
                          {;}
                          break;
                      default :
                          {i++;}
                          }}
                      i=0;
                      j=0;
                      }
            else{i++;}}

#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_interupt(void)
{
    if(GT<86459)//24:00:59 in seconds
        {GT++;}//add a second
    else
        {GT=60;}//00:01:00
    if(timercount<299)//300s=5min
    {timercount++;}
    else{timercount=0;
         ADC10CTL0 |= 0x3;// turn on ADC
         while(ADC10CTL1 & ADC10BUSY)//loop to alow for ADC to finish sampeling
                 {;;}
         ADC10CTL0 & 0xFFFE;//Shuting off the ADC after sampeling
         tempature[i]=ADC10MEM;//Storing the tempature
         tempaturetime[i]=GT;// storing the time
         if(i<31)
             {i++;}
         else
             {i=0;}
        }
}
```

Comment: the posted code is 'mostly' unreadable.  Suggest: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default by a single blank line. 2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both).

Comment: treat `{` and `}` as separate statements

Comment: `volatile short unsigned int i=0,j=0,k=0;` :: global variables with one-letter names are *reserved for scientists*

Answer (score 0):

one very obvious problem with the posted code is that when the currently being checked input char is found to be `x` is the new date stamp must have been entered (as 6 digits) after the user entered `x` but before the user entered a `\r`  this could be made to work, but there is no code enforcing that sequence of input.

in general, the uart input function should contain several 'states and sub states'  where a command char causes the code to switch to a 'state' and that would have sub states for the actual time stamp. so when the user inputs a command, like `x` a mode is set, where the next 6 digits entered are the new timestamp.

suggest designing a 'context sensitive' state diagram then implementing that diagram.

amongst other things, the size of the input buffer would  reduced to 1 byte

amongst the many sequencing problems there is the fact that when accumulating some number, saying things like

```
int temp = 0;
temp += inputchar[x] - 0x30;
temp += inputchar[x+1] - 0x30;
...
```

will not generate the expected results.

what would generate the expected results would be:

```
int temp = 0;
temp += inputchar[x] - 0x30;
temp = temp*10 + (inputchar[x+1] - 0x30);
....
temp = temp*10 + (inputchar[x+5] - 0x30);
GT = temp;
```

and of course, test each inputchar using if( isdigit( inputchar[x] ) before trying to apply that input to the calculation of `temp`

for ease of development, strongly suggest only try to implement one command at a time and when that command is working properly (make extensive use of a debugger to make the testing easy. such as a `jtag` debugger for that chip.)  Then move on to the next command to implement.

the variable `i` is being modified in both interrupt handlers.  So when one interrupt handler modifies `i`, the value is corrupted for the other interrupt.

one full day (24 hours) is 878400 seconds so the value 86459 is not correct.  Also, this is a 'magic' number in the code.  magic numbers have no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.  Note: resetting the `GT` counter to 60 is not correct, in the posted code it should be reset to 0.

Similar considerations exist for the 'magic' number 300.

the posted code has no action when the input command is `l` so we cannot analyze such (non existent) code to determine what is wrong with it.

in the handling of the `t` command:

the `GT` variable is subject to modification between access.  Suggest saving to a 'new' variable and do all calculations from that new variable.

the calculation of `h`, `m`, and `s` is performing a lot of re-calculation of the same intermediate variables.  Suggest:

```
int myGT = GT;
h = myGT / 3600;
myGT %= 3600;
m = myGT / 60;
s = myGT % 60;
```

The array `test[]` is set but not used.  This is a waste of resources in production code.   Suggest its' existence and setting be determined by some `-D` compiler parameter.